# How to observe PagedList data?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm using [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) and Android Architecture Components. I simply want to observe pagedlist livedata and update my RecyclerView when there is a change.

I'm observing isLoadingLiveData, isEmptyLiveData and errorLiveData objects which are MediatorLiveData objects created in my ViewModel and observed in my fragment. And also observing resultLiveData which returns the fetched Gist list from remote.

In my ViewModel, I created a PagedList LiveData and whenever it's data changed, I wanted to update isLoadingLiveData, isEmptyLiveData, errorLiveData and [PagedListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter.html). Therefore, I defined isLoadingLiveData, isEmptyLiveData, errorLiveData and resultLiveData as MediatorLiveData objects. I added resultLiveData as a source of these objects. So when resultLiveData has changed, these objects' onChanged methods will be called. And resultLiveData is depend on userNameLiveData, so when userNameLiveData has changed, allGistsLiveData will be called and it will fetch the data. For example when the user swipe the list, I'm setting userNameLiveData and doing network call again.

My ViewModel:

```
private val userNameLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
private var gists: LiveData<PagedList<Gist>>? = null

val allGistsLiveData: LiveData<PagedList<Gist>>
    get() {
        if (null == gists) {
            gists = GistModel(NetManager(getApplication()), getApplication()).getYourGists(userNameLiveData.value!!).create(0,
                    PagedList.Config.Builder()
                            .setPageSize(PAGED_LIST_PAGE_SIZE)
                            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(PAGED_LIST_PAGE_SIZE)
                            .setEnablePlaceholders(PAGED_LIST_ENABLE_PLACEHOLDERS)
                            .build())
        }
        return gists!!
    }

val resultLiveData = MediatorLiveData<LiveData<PagedList<Gist>>>().apply {
    this.addSource(userNameLiveData) {
        gists = null
        this.value = allGistsLiveData
    }
}


val isLoadingLiveData = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>().apply {
    this.addSource(resultLiveData) { this.value = false }
}

val isEmptyLiveData = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>().apply {
    this.addSource(resultLiveData) { this.value = false }
}

val errorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>().apply {
    this.addSource(resultLiveData) {
        if (it == null) {
            this.value = true
        }
    }
}

fun setUserName(userName: String) {
    userNameLiveData.value = userName
}
```

and my fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel.isEmptyLiveData.observe(this@YourGistsFragment, Observer<Boolean> { isVisible ->
        emptyView.visibility = if (isVisible!!) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    })

    viewModel.isLoadingLiveData.observe(this@YourGistsFragment, Observer<Boolean> {
        it?.let {
            swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = it
        }
    })

    viewModel.errorLiveData.observe(this@YourGistsFragment, Observer<Boolean> {
        it?.let {
            showSnackBar(context.getString(R.string.unknown_error))
        }
    })

    viewModel.setUserName("melomg")
    viewModel.resultLiveData.observe(this@YourGistsFragment, Observer { it -> gistAdapter.setList(it?.value) })
}


override fun onRefresh() {
    viewModel.setUserName("melomg")
}
```

my repository:

```
fun getYourGists(userName: String): LivePagedListProvider<Int, Gist> {
    return remoteDataSource.getYourGists(userName, GitHubApi.getGitHubService(context))
}
```

my remoteDataSource:

```
fun getYourGists(username: String, dataProvider: GitHubService): LivePagedListProvider<Int, Gist> {
    return object : LivePagedListProvider<Int, Gist>() {
        override fun createDataSource(): GistTiledRemoteDataSource<Gist> = object : GistTiledRemoteDataSource<Gist>(username, dataProvider) {
            override fun convertToItems(items: ArrayList<Gist>?): ArrayList<Gist>? {
                return items
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to create this solution from [this project](https://github.com/KucherenkoIhor/Android-Architecture-Components). But my problem is
resultLiveData has been changing without waiting the network call response and therefore the result of response ignored and my ui is being updated before the data has arrived. Since resultLiveData is changing before request and therefore there is no data yet. Simply how can I observe  pagedlist livedata?

Comment: @pskink nothing wrong with `LivePagedListProvider. GistModel().getYourGists() `returns `LiveData<PagedList>`. but I want to observe LivePagedListProvider's data which is `ArrayList<Gist>` not itself. the problem is that allGistsLiveData is changing when it is initialized not when data come back from remote.

Comment: @pskink I added my repository and remoteDataSource classes to show LivePagedListProvider implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a working solution but I don't think it is a best solution. So if you have any ideas please don't hesitate to answer. Here is my solution:

I gave up from wrapping my [PagedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList.html) data with [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData.html). I still leave my all other live data(`isLoadingLiveData, isEmptyLiveData, errorLiveData`) as `MediatorLiveData` but added their source when my gists PagedList LiveData initialized. Here is the code:

```
private var gists: LiveData<PagedList<Gist>>? = null
private val userNameLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
val isLoadingLiveData = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>()
val isEmptyLiveData = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>()
val errorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<ErrorMessage>()

val allGistsLiveData: LiveData<PagedList<Gist>>
    get() {
        if (gists == null) {
                gists = GistModel(NetManager(getApplication()), getApplication()).getYourGists(userNameLiveData.value!!).create(0,
                        PagedList.Config.Builder()
                                .setPageSize(Constants.PAGED_LIST_PAGE_SIZE)
                                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(Constants.PAGED_LIST_PAGE_SIZE)
                                .setEnablePlaceholders(Constants.PAGED_LIST_ENABLE_PLACEHOLDERS)
                                .build())


                isLoadingLiveData.addSource(gists) { isLoadingLiveData.value = false }
                isEmptyLiveData.addSource(gists) {
                    if (it?.size == 0) {
                        isEmptyLiveData.value = true
                    }
                }
                errorLiveData.addSource(gists) {
                    if (it == null) {
                        errorLiveData.value = ErrorMessage(errorCode = ErrorCode.GENERAL_ERROR)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return gists!!
    }


fun setUserName(userName: String) {
    isLoadingLiveData.value = true
    userNameLiveData.value = userName
    gists = null
    allGistsLiveData
}
```

Comment: I hope sometime the Android guys will come up with a solution for MediatorLiveData capable using Paging. Like a MediatorLivePagedListBuilder. We should file it on our wish lists

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do this. Look this example:

https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample

The trick is putting inside your DataSource a mutable live data like this:

```
enum class NetworkState { LOADING, LOADED, FAILURE }

val networkState = MutableLiveData<NetworkState>()

override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<String>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<String,  OrderService.Resource>) {
    networkState.post(NetworkState.LOADING)
    ApiClient.listMyObjects(
            onSuccess = { list ->
                networkState.post(NetworkState.LOADED)
                callback.onResult(list)
            }
            onFailure = {
                networkState.post(NetworkState.FAILURE)
            }
    )
}
```

Then you can listen to your paged list and network state with:

```
val myDataSource = MyDataSource.Factory().create()
myDataSource.toLiveData().observe(viewLifeCycle, Observer { pagedList ->
    // Update your recycler view
    myRecyclerViewAdapter.submitList(pagedList)
})
myDataSource.networkState.observe(viewLifeCycle, Observer { state ->
    // Show errors, retry button, progress view etc. according to state  
})
```